SAM CLI - Error: Not supported URL scheme http+docker
I seem to be getting an error after performing a general upgrade of my packages. I am running the following command which was working fine before the upgrade:
sam local start-api --profile msoft-dev --skip-pull-image -p 4000 -t cdk.out/local.template.json -n local.env.json

Now it produces the following error:

Error: Not supported URL scheme http+docker

I've had a look online but could not find anything particularly helpful. Anyone come across this or know what may be the issue?

This a problem coming from requests==2.32.x, downgrading this to requests==2.31 will fix it.
